# (drupal) Webform2pdf blank submitted data tokens when PDF send by mail

Tags: email, pdf, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-webform

I run into an issue with module `webform2pdf`, which I am too unable to solve for a few days. I am using Commerce Kickstart as a drupal commerce module for handling all the shopping fuctionality, and we were in need to add webforms for returns policy (required by law in my country).

This form has many fields, like when you have pursached the product, what is it's serial number etc. `Webform2pdf` module was used for sending submitted data as PDF as attachment to email. But the received PDF by mail has blank data tokens, no matter how I try. Weird thing is, that when I hit `download PDF` in administration of drupal website, it just fills the data tokens right.

I have tried many tokens, all of these:

```
[submission:values:meno:withlabel]

 [submission:values:meno]

 [webform:val-meno]

 [webform:meno]

 %email[meno]

 %email_values

 %label_nl[meno]

 %nl[meno]

 %label_all[meno]

 %label_all_nl[meno]

 %all[meno]

 %all_nl[meno]

[submission:values]

%value[meno]
```

Neither of them works, most of them simply prints token label. For example `[submission:values]` prints all the labels, but no data.

Upper in the mail, I have also token:

```
%label_all[typ_servisu]
```

Which prints correctly when sent via mail, but refuses to print when "download PDF" in administration. This token holds select radio buttons.

I have also tried send pdf as attachment via Rules, but with no success. I am not very experienced developer.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.